# Как в Django вызвать функцию c параметрами из HTML template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

views.py

```
def ConnectChannels(request, c_id, rx_id):
    connect_channels = requests.get(
        'http://192.168.1.1/api/?v=5&method=connect_channel&token=' + token + '&c_id=' + c_id + '&rx_id=' + rx_id + '&mode=s')

    return render(request, 'gui/chanel_list.html',
                  {"channels": connect_channels})
```

html template

```
<div class="card-group">
    {% for item in channels %}
    <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"> {{ item.c_name }}</h5>
            <p class="text-left" class="card-text">
                Video1: {{ item.c_video1 }}
                <br>
                MAC: {{ item.mode }}
                <br>
                SHARED BUTTON: {{ item.shared_button}}
                <br>
                ID: {{ item.c_id }}
            </p>
            <button onclick="window.location='{% url 'connect_channel' %}'" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                Выбрать
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('/connect_channel', views.ConnectChannels(), name='connect_channel'),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можешь написать свой тег, который возвращает результат твоей функции в шаблон. Подробнее [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

> {% your_tag param1 param2 %}